# Extract p-value from ucm class object

Tags: r, p-value

I am using `rucm` package, I have a ucm class object called multivar_ucm. When I just type multivar_ucm in r console and hit enter I get the beta estimates of all exogenous variables along with standard error and p values printed in the r console.

I could get the beta coefficients by using `as.data.frame(multivar_ucm$est)` and write it in a csv file. Looking for a similar approach to export the respective p values as well.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the package does not expose the object’s *p*-value (this is somewhat of an oversight). The `print.ucm` method recomputes the value every time. If you want to get the object’s *p*-value, [you’ll need to do the same](https://github.com/kaushikrch/rucm/blob/a14c45b32226e482193cf03dceea5874ae5ffc73/R/print.ucm.R#L10-L13):

```
t_value = x$est / attr(x, "se")
p_value = 2 * pt(-abs(t_value), df = attr(x, "df"))
```

(Code cleaned up slightly.)

Comment: Thank you, @KonradRudolph. Worked like a charm!